# How to pass user input from GUI to main class

Tags: java, program-entry-point, actionlistener

I'm just starting to work with Java Swing again and I have the same problem as last time.
I want to write a program which reads some user input, executes an algorithm and displays the result. The program has to work with two different user interfaces (console and GUI with Java Swing).

Currently I have a packet of classes with the algorithm (i can just pass in the user input and fetch the result), a class which contains the main class, a class for the console interface and a class for the GUI (which extends from JFrame).
Some code:

```
public class Algorithm {
//a lot of code
}
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(...) {
        Algorithm algorithm = new Algorithm();
        //use either console or GUI and read user input
        algorithm.execute(user input);
        algorithm.getResult();
        //display result on console/GUI
    }
}
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
}
```

My Problem is that I don't know how to pass the user input (text, scalers and radio buttons, button) from the GUI to the algorithm and how to display the result on the GUI.

Do I have to pass an instance of Algorithm to the GUI and call the methods of Algorithm from GUI?
Or is it possible to implement the ActionsListener in MainClass (where I have an instance of Algorithm)? If I choose this way of implementation, how can i pass the result of the Algorithm back to the GUI?
Or should i change the whole implementation? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Don't (at least not to the Main class).

Long answer: There is a pattern called Model-View-Controller (MVC) which explains how to get data from the user, do something with it and display it again. This link (and the whole site in general) is a good point to start: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Applied to your code sample:

```
public class Algorithm {
//a lot of code
}
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(...) {
        Algorithm algorithm = new Algorithm();
        GUI g = new GUI(algorithm );
    }
}
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private Algorithm algo;
    public GUI(Algorithm a) { this.algo = a; }
}
```

`Algorithm` plays the role of the model here and `GUI` is a combination of controller and view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the Algorithm nicely encapsulated in its own class then it should be easy to instantiate on object of type Algorithm in response to a button click on your GUI and execute the algorithm there. The main method shoul donly decide if the GUI is necessary and start it up.

So if you have a button called calculate on your GUI then:

```
  calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               //get the user input from the JFrame
               Algorithm algorithm = new Algorithm();
               algorithm.execute(user input);
               algorithm.getResult();
               //display results on the JFrame
          }
  });
```

Getting input from a JTextField and so on is as simple as

```
  mytextfield.getText();
```

and to write some value into a JLabel to display is:

```
  mylabel.setText("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Observer Pattern. In this case algorithm is the java.util.Observer and Gui is the java.util.Observable.

Comment: He's already using the observer pattern! (ActionListener) The Algorithm should'nt need to register at the GUI at all, since thats the controllers job. If there's no controller, its the job of the GUI to know all the logic.